# removing style attribute with regex in asp

Tags: regex, string, asp-classic, vbscript

How can i remove style attribute from any tag with regex in asp?

```
from:

<div style="margin-top:10px;">test</div>

to:

<div>test</div>



Set objRegExp = New regexp
objRegExp.Pattern = "/style\s*=\s*(\'|').+(\'|')/i"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
Set resp = objRegExp.Execute(strWordHTML)
For Each respItem In resp
    strWordHTML= replace(strWordHTML,respItem.Value,"")
Next
Set resp = Nothing
Set objRegExp = Nothing
```

solved ***

```
(\sstyle=['""][^'""]+?['""])
```

Comment: just trying to modify a code. but it s dont work.

Comment: in `objRegExp.Pattern = "/style\s*=\s*(\'|').+(\'|')/i"`, the starting `/` and end `/i` will be interpreted as part of the pattern so you can remove them. `/i` is accounted for by `objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True`

Comment: Just what oracle certified professional says, and look at your quote marks. `'` does not need to be escaped and is not going to work for `"` so you have to indicate them. In VBScript `"` is escaped by a second pair of bunny ears: `""`. Your regexp pattern _string_ should be something like: `"style\s*=\s*[""'].+[""']"`

Answer (score 2):

Not using regex and not tested but something like this should work

```
str = "<div style=""margin-top:10px;"">test</div>"
start = InStr(str, "style")
first = InStr(start, str, """")
second = InStr(first, str, """")

result = Mid(str, 1, start - 1) + Mid(str, second + 1)
```

Comment: To escape quotation mark, I think you have to do double quotation mark.

Answer (score -1):

```
 dim result = Regex.Replace(HtmlText, "style[^>]*", "")
```